# Problema al hacer un INSERT en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Veamos, tengo un array con unos ean (IDs) y quiero insertarlos en una tabla de MySQL. El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
foreach ($resultadoComparaArrays as $key => $value) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO articulos_nuevos (`ean`) VALUES"." (".$value.")";
    $resultado=mysql_query($conWebService, $sql);
    if($resultado){
            echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".$value." "."fue insertado correctamente.";
        }else{
            echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".$value." "."tuvo errores en la inserción en su correspondiente tabla. Se aconseja que se revise. El error tuvo que ver con.".mysql_error();
        }
}
```

Pues bien, me da error porque me dice que "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query()". Llevo un muy buen rato dándole vueltas, pero no veo el error por ningún lado, ¿a qué se puede deber? Muchas gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica probablemente en la consulta misma.
Debes verificar que version de PHP estas usando.

```
$resultado=mysql_query($conWebService, $sql);
```

Esta extensión fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0. En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones `MySQLi` o `PDO_MySQL`.
Es decir, tu lo más probable es que tu consulta deba ser:

```
$resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
```

Comment: Efectivamente. Así es. Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: De nada, un placer ayudar ;)

Comment: Solo como añadido, es mejor que el bucle cree una cadena con todos los `values` que quieres añadir, y luego ejecutar una única consulta. Sino estás generando varias consultas, lo cual es bastante más lento

Answer (score 1):

Ya que estas trabajando con MySQL, podrías probar con la función `mysqli_query()`, quedando de esta forma:

```
foreach ($resultadoComparaArrays as $key => $value) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO articulos_nuevos (`ean`) VALUES"." (".$value.")";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
    if($resultado){
            echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".$value." "."fue insertado correctamente.";
        }else{
            echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".$value." "."tuvo errores en la inserción en su correspondiente tabla. Se aconseja que se revise. El error tuvo que ver con.".mysql_error();
        }
}
```